# Could not find json-1.6.5 in Jenkins CI

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, sinatra, jenkins

I have a Jenkins CI server and when I run following build script I get errors:

```
rdoc spec
```

Here is the errors:

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 -S rspec spec/requests/home_spec.rb
/home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize': Could not find json-1.6.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `materialize'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:117:in `setup'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/App1/workspace/config/boot.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/App1/workspace/spec/spec_helper.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/App1/workspace/spec/requests/home_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/zeck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
```

Here is the my Rakefile:

```
require 'rdoc/task'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc 'Generate test result'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.pattern = 'spec/*/*_spec.rb'
end
```

And here is the my Gemfile:

```
source :rubygems

# Required gems
gem 'sinatra', '>= 1.3.2'
gem 'rdoc', '>= 3.12'
gem 'rake'
gem 'json', '>= 1.6.5'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '>= 2.9.0'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'simplecov', '>= 0.6.1', require: false
end
```

I don't have any idea. Please help me. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM.

Thank you for every advise. Sorry for poor English :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the reason is that environment where Jenkins is running your build is different than the environment where you run the build.

Usually the difference is caused by an environment variable which is set for you but not for Jenkins

You can check your environment variables by running the command `env`. You can check Jenkins' environment at Manage Jenkins -> System Information.

If you need to set some environment variables, you can do it at Manage Jenkins -> Configure System.